# How to get rid of Evaluate() without local scope (pre-CF9)?

Tags: coldfusion

Ok, this func doesn't make sense, but I'm just using it as an example:

```
<cffunction name="blah">
    <cfset var myFoo = 123>
    <cfset var varNamePrefix = "my">

    <cfset var bar = Evaluate("#varNamePrefix#Foo")>

    <cfreturn bar>
</cffunction>
```

With CF9, I can use `local["#varNamePrefix#Foo"]`.  Is there a way for CF7/8 to get rid of the `Evaluate()` without refactoring the whole thing with `var local = structNew()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not by documented means. Pre-CF9 there is only [getPageContext().getActiveFunctionLocalScope()](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/2/17/coldfusion.8.local.function.scope)

```
<cffunction name="blah">
    <cfset var myFoo = 123>
    <cfset var varNamePrefix = "my">
    <!--- ie object.method()[keyName] syntax does not seem to be supported --->
    <cfset var localScope = getPageContext().getActiveFunctionLocalScope()>
    <cfset var bar = localScope["#varNamePrefix#Foo"]>

    <cfreturn bar>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: And we need to get rid of that call when it's time to upgrade to CF9+?

Comment: I tested it and getActiveFunctionLocalScope still exists in 9.0.1. But who knows what will happen after that.